# .getJSON passing variable data with same name

Tags: jquery

I have a problem when passing data in .getJSON. The reason for this is because I need to pass variables with same name.  So, I have a client in python and I do this with that code :

```
query_args = { 'name':[var1,var2,var3] }

output = urllib2.urlopen('http://'+servername+':'+port+'/'+action,urllib.urlencode(query_args,doseq=True))
```

if i try to do that in javasctipt with .getJSON, i try to do

```
$.getJSON(
    "http://servername::8001/SearchNode",
    {
        name: "name",
        name: "google"
    },
    function(data) {

        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            console.log(key);
            console.log(val);
        });
    }   
);
```

When I debug query string I see only one of the variables.  Can anyone give me a simple solution to my problem?

Regards

Comment: Another nice question. And ah, surprise, you just reached upvote levels ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass multiple objects within one variable you must use another structure. In your case you want both the string *name* and *google* to be sent. By using your method you simply override the value of the variable name.

There are multiple ways to solve this problem. I must say, that I haven't used python for a while now (So phytoneers out there, feel free to correct me).

**idea 1:**
Rename parameters in js-code and glue them together in python. Change one key of your 2 parameters, so they don't override...

```
$.getJSON(
    "http://servername::8001/SearchNode",
    {
        name1: "name", 
        name2: "google"
    },
    function(data) {...}
)
```

...and afterwards rebuild your array...

```
query_args = {'name': [name1, name2] }
```

*or* alternatively don't bother with query_args, but rather handle them directly into your urllib.urlencode

```
output = urllib2.urlopen('yoururl', urllib.urlencode({'name':[name1, name2]}, True))
```

**idea 2:**
This is probably what you want to do. Put both strings inside an array and sent this as a parameter. At [json.org](http://www.json.org/) you can have a look at different kinds of datastructures send via ajax.
In this case, your code would look like this:

```
$.getJSON(
    "http://servername::8001/SearchNode",
    {
        name: ["name", "google"]
    },
    function(data) {...}
)
```

Using this method, you can easily add even more parameters, without adding so many different variables that you need to concat later.
Since I'm not that familiar with python anymore, I can't tell you how python will store this (probably a list). But either way, you should be able to handle this as well into the urlencode function. (At least the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) says, it must be a sequence, which this list certainly is)